# Android GoogleCredential invalid credentials

Tags: android, credentials, google-drive-android-api

I have an access token for Google Drive which is received from server. After receiving I try initialize `GoogleCredential` with this token and then perform requests to Drive API. But when I try perform requests I catch next stack trace:

```
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err: {
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:   "code" : 401,
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     "location" : "Authorization",
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     "locationType" : "header",
04-13 15:23:22.715 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     "reason" : "authError"
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:   } ],
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err: }
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.GoogleDriveHelper.getQuotaInfo(GoogleDriveHelper.java:163)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.GoogleDriveHelper.addCloud(GoogleDriveHelper.java:100)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.GoogleDriveHelper.initClient(GoogleDriveHelper.java:93)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.GoogleDriveHelper.<init>(GoogleDriveHelper.java:53)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.GoogleDriveHelper.getInstance(GoogleDriveHelper.java:107)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.StoragesHelper.getGoogleDriveHelper(StoragesHelper.java:135)
04-13 15:23:22.716 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.storages.helpers.StoragesHelper.initClients(StoragesHelper.java:97)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.utils.CloudStorageCollector.saveCloudsToDatabase(CloudStorageCollector.java:61)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.services.SyncApiService.getOldCloudsSync(SyncApiService.java:205)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.services.SyncApiService.startCloudSync(SyncApiService.java:194)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.services.SyncApiService.handleActionFullSync(SyncApiService.java:176)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at com.rcd.perfecto.services.SyncApiService.onHandleIntent(SyncApiService.java:153)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
04-13 15:23:22.717 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-13 15:23:22.718 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-13 15:23:22.718 29184-29570/com.rcd.perfecto W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

There's how I initialize credentials and perform requests to Drive:

```
private void initClient() {
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    try {
        GoogleClientSecrets googleClientSecrets = loadClientSecretsResource(mContext, jsonFactory);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setClientSecrets(googleClientSecrets)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setTransport(transport)
                .build();
        credential.setAccessToken(AppPreferences.Storage.GoogleDrive.getToken(mContext));
        credential.refreshToken();
        mService = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();
        addCloud();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addCloud() {
    Map<String, Long> quotaInfo = getQuotaInfo();
    CloudStorageCollector.saveCloudToDatabase(AppPreferences.Storage.GoogleDrive.getToken(mContext), BaseVault.VaultCode.GoogleDriveVault,
            quotaInfo.get(StoragesHelper.USED_QUOTA_KEY), quotaInfo.get(StoragesHelper.TOTAL_QUOTA_KEY));
}

public Map<String, Long> getQuotaInfo() {
    if (mService == null) return null;
    Map<String, Long> quotaInfo = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        About about = mService.about().get().execute();
        quotaInfo.put(StoragesHelper.USED_QUOTA_KEY, about.getQuotaBytesUsed());
        quotaInfo.put(StoragesHelper.TOTAL_QUOTA_KEY, about.getQuotaBytesTotal());
        return quotaInfo;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

In `getQuotaInfo` method I catch the Exception. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error [401: Invalid Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) or invalid authorization header means that the access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

So try to refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, try to check again the [authorizing requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing). Here is the steps:

1. When you create your application, you register it using the *Google Developers Console*. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
2. Activate the Drive API in the Google Developers Console. (If the API isn't listed in the Developers Console, then skip this step.)
3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular *scope* of access.
4. Google displays a *consent screen* to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
6. Your application requests user data, attaching the *access token* to the request.
7. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

Some flows include additional steps, such as using *refresh tokens* to acquire new access tokens. For detailed information about flows for various types of applications, see [Google's OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).